# Generic class doesn't have the same return type as its interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I want to have a generic class for my parameter value and return its contents using an interface method, but I have a compile error about not having the matching return type. Is there a way to fix this? My code below:

```
    public class Parameter
    {
        public Parameter(String name, int value)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = eType.typeInt;
            this.parameterValue = new ParameterValueTemplate<int>(value);
        }

        public Parameter(String name, double value)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = eType.typeDouble;
            this.parameterValue = new ParameterValueTemplate<double>(value);
        }

        public interface IParameterValue
        {
            int GetValue();
        }

        class ParameterValueTemplate<T> : IParameterValue
        {
            public ParameterValueTemplate(T value)
            {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public T GetValue()
            {
                return value;
            }

            T value;
        }

        public String name;
        public IParameterValue parameterValue;
    }
```

Comment: Your interface also has to be generic. It's complaining probably because you require `int` as the return type from the interface for any generic parameter value template.

Comment: Your class declaration is wrong for your usage. If you expect `T` to be `IParameterValue`, you need a generic constraint on `T`, not to implement the interface in your generic class.

Comment: Ugh. Why would you ever *nest* an interface. That completely defeats the point of an interface!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I agree, it's probably because he's seen people constructing with interfaces for DI and resolving purposes.. it does defeat the purpose here though.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. I wanted to factorize the code into a generic class and not have to write an implementation for each type of value inside my parameter. But I guess I'll have to do it, write a derived class for int, double and string.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, what do you mean?  A nested interface is exactly as useful as a non-nested one except that you (might) have to qualify its name with `Parameter.`.  I'm not saying it's a great idea here (or necessarily anywhere), but I'm not sure in what sense it "completely defeats the point of an interface".  Can you provide an example in which it detracts from the purpose of an interface?

Comment: @KirkWoll An interface exposes a contract to the outside world, so by nesting it, its now a "part of" a `Parameter` object. How does that make any idiomatic sense? (Granted, I'm against nested types in general, so my opinion is quite biased).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, an interface exposes a contract -- possibly to the outside world -- and possibly to your own internal classes of your library.  Perhaps you're quixotic and you group a bunch of related interfaces in an `Interfaces` class.  *I* wouldn't recommend it, but it doesn't change the semantics, functionality, behavior, or frankly anything about the interface or its implementation.

Comment: @KirkWoll I agree with you completely. I guess my point is that I don't see a reasonable, real-world reason to ever do this. Hence; defeating the point of an interface (perhaps worded poorly).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, fair enough, i take your point too.

Comment: @PedroNF: the only thing you _have_ to fix here is to change the interface declaration to look like this -- `public interface IParameterValue<T> { T GetValue(); }` -- and then declare the template type like this -- `class ParameterValueTemplate<T> : IParameterValue<T>`. But it's not really clear from your question when that addresses any broader issue you might have with the design here.

Comment: I want to have a Parameter class that I save into a single Dictionary<String, Parameter>, so I can't have Parameter as a generic class. The parameter class consists of a Name and a Value. Inside the Value I can be able to save a int, double or String.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: If the interface is generic then I can't have a single ParameterValue in my Parameter class. The interface needs to hide the type of the value.

Comment: @PedroNF: "The interface needs to hide the type of the value" -- even as a non-generic, it can't do that. You either make it generic, or you pick a type. Either way, the type of the value is known. The only way to completely disregard the type of the value is to use `object` as the type. That said, nothing about my suggestion requires the _`Parameter`_ type to be generic; just the interface and the implementing type (which you've already made generic anyway).

Comment: I feel like this question is suffering from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps if you can explain to what end you are needing this type of functionality you can get better answers.

Comment: It is not clear what you want `GetValue()` to return. Is it _always_ `int` via conversion, is it nullable `int`, is it `object`, or is `T` whatever the template uses?

Comment: Are you trying to create [a reference to a value type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2256048/380384)?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a completely different way...!
I wanted to have a generic parameter class that can contain different types of values inside, but the rest of the code was already typed so I ended up using a struct for storage and a dictionary for fast parameter search by name :-)