# Keeping a value type in synch, dependency property, reference, event or redesign?

Tags: c#, pointers, events, dependency-properties

**Problem:**

I have a value type (a struct) that needs to is held in a class that is updated by a different class.

*What is the "C#" way of solving this efficiently?*

**Approaches**

I have put the basic "boiled down" code below. It would seem it could be solved 3 ways:

1. Make "matrix" a dependency property
2. Send "model" around instead of "matrix"
3. Raise a model changed event that the controllers subscribe to and then update the model.matrix
4. [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258102/1044650)

I am relatively new to C# and being from a C++ background I would have just sent a pointer to position (which seems to be **4** in effect). However it feels very "un-C#" and looking back feels like "un-designed"!

However my assumption is **1**:dependency properties (which seems like the "C#" way) seem like they are side stepping design in more or less the same way and I am concerned about the level of indirection.

My current issue with **2** is that the Modifiers are responsible for updating the "matrix" they don't really need to know about everything else in the model and ideally shouldn't even need to deal with it.

**3** feels like a hand rolled version of **2**, but feels like it would be more efficient

**About the Data:**

Multiple instances of "matrix" will be **read a lot** but only 1/2 will be written too at any one time, at most during mouse move events.

**Example Code**

```
class Model
{
    glm.mat4 position; //mat4 is a struct i.e. a value type
}

class MouseControll
{
    MatrixModifiyer Modifier = new MatrixModifiyer()
    MouseControll(Model model)
    {
        Modifier.BindToMatrix(model.matrix);
    }
    //invoke modifier based on mouse events
}
class InterfaceControll
{
    MatrixModifiyer Modifier = new MatrixModifiyer()
    InterfaceControll(Model model)
    {
        Modifier.BindToMatrix(model.matrix);
    }
    //invoke modifier based on button events
}

class MatrixModifiyer
{
    glm.mat4 camera;       //how do I have position in sync with camera?
    glm.vec2 position;
    void BindToMatrix(mat4 matrix)
    {
        camera = matrix;
    }
    void PanMatrix()
    {
        //modify matrix params
        position = ...
        CalculateNewMatrix();
    }
    void CalculateNewMatrix()
    {
        //calculat new matrix;
        camera = translate(camera, position)
        ...

        //at this point I want model.matrix to be updated
    }

    glm.mat4 GetMatrix()
    {
        return camera;
    }
}

class App
{
    void Start()
    {
        Model aModel = new Model();
        InterfaceControll interface = new InterfaceControll(aModel);
        MouseControll interface = new MouseControll(aModel);
        //register mouse controll with mouse events

        //register interface control with button events
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main concern for you here, is your understanding of C# pass-by-* semantics. With C#, all parameters are passed by *value*, not by reference, it just so happens that the value of a reference type, is its memory location, so the value being passed around always points to the same instance of the reference type. I'm assuming you want to be able to pass your value type around, and all consumers are always aware of changes to it?

I think the optimal design for this is to use a container reference type, e.g. in your case, perhaps something like:

```
class GlmParameters
{
    public glm.mat4 position { get; set; }
}
```

Or perhaps just pass your `Model` type around as this is effectively what it is already:

```
class MatrixModifier
{
    private Model _model;

    void BindToMatrix(Model model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    void PanMatrix()
    {
        _model.position = //
        CalculateNewMatrix();
    }

    void CalculateNewMatrix()
    {
        translate(_model);
    }
}
```

Another side-effect to consider, is that value types should ideally be **immutable**, because of the pass-by-value semantics:

```
struct MyImmutableStruct
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public MyImmutableStruct(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get { return _value; } }
}
```

Let's look at this in action:

```
var first = new MyImmutableStruct(1);
var second = first;

Console.WriteLine(first.Value);     // Prints 1
Console.WriteLine(second.Value);    // Prints 1
```

Vs.

```
struct MyMutableStruct
{
    private int _value;

    public MyMutableStruct(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
}

var third = new MyMutableStruct(1);
var fourth = third;
// Set a new value.
fourth.Value = 2;

Console.WriteLine(third.Value);     // Still prints 1
Console.WriteLine(fourth.Value);    // Prints 2
```

You'll notice because of `fourth` is a copy of `third`, it is not the *same instance*, therefore any changes to the `fourth` instances, aren't reflected. Of course, you can get around this by using a reference type instead, or using `ref` parameters when passing values round.