# Data structure for simple animations in games

Tags: c#, data-structures, reference, opentk

I'm trying to create a system in which numbers are changed according to the time elapsed since last update, their target/destination value, etc.

In an earlier project, I created an abstract class for animation data which contained Tick(), IsDone(), etc, which were then implemented for each facet of the game object I wanted to animate, such as position and opacity. The animation data were held by the game object, with the Tick() function being called by the game object's Tick() function, which is called by the engine's logic update loop using a list of all game objects.

However, I now have more things I want to animate, and was looking in to doing so with as few classes as possible, and definitely not with N+1 classes.

I looked in to saving references to the variable being animated, using the fact that all variables I wanted to animate were floats. However, it appears C# pointers are analogs to the C pointers, and so I cannot save pointers to the values being animated, which appears to be impossible for the CLR in the first place.

The only alternative I could think of is to use reflection to record the argument being passed, then use reflection again to find the value to alter each tick. But then using dozens of reflection calls 60 times a second did not appeal to me.

Since animating objects is a near universal feature in games, I was wondering if there were established practices.

Comment: There is. In wpf have a look at [Animatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.ianimatable(v=vs.110).aspx). This however required introducing a whole new concept of dependency properties, not yet talking about performance. If I would be you, then I would stop using `float` directly, but some `AnimatableFloat` (if you use [conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664464(v=vs.71).aspx) then usage can still be the same), which supports attaching animations.

Comment: Thanks, but as you said yourself, that would require using WPF, which would complicate the already complicated .net Graphics / OpenTK conflicts. Also, the interface doesn't appear to fix any of the problems I mentioned.

Comment: Lot of words here, recommend you show some code. Because I can't follow some of this like: "However, it appears C# pointers are analogs to the C pointers, and so I cannot save pointers to the values being animated, which appears to be impossible for the CLR in the first place." - Why?

Comment: I found quite a few answers repeat the message, and here's one of them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2258102 It looks like a limitation / design choice of CLR.