# What are methods exist to have some variables that reference the same value-typed value?

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

For example C has a pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int src = 10;
    int* t1 = &src;
    int* t2 = &src;
    *t1 = 20;
    printf("%d, %d, %d", *t1, *t2, src); //20, 20, 20
    return 0;
}
```

But what about C#? For example, we can wrap an int variable into the class:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    public class IntWrapper {
        public int value;
        public IntWrapper(int value) { this.value = value; }
        public override String ToString() => value.ToString();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var src = new IntWrapper(10);
        var t1 = src;
        var t2 = src;
        t1.value = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", t1, t2, src)); // 20, 20, 20
    }
}
```

Are there simpler way to do this in C#? Or may be the best way...

Comment: C# has `ref`, but before C# 7 it's quite restricted in where you can use it. What is the actual thing you need this for?

Comment: @harold: In C# 7 it's still very restricted in where you can use `ref`.

Comment: @Memphis: One obvious improvement is to make the wrapper generic.

Comment: In C# you can use pointers in [unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) context.

Comment: @harold: Not for any special purposes, just interesting thing in which I am not sure. And, C# 7 does has `ref` that is really appropriate for this situation. Thanks.

Comment: I found related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2256048/6624666