# Is there a way to store a reference to a reference of an object?

Tags: c#

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test[] tests = new Test[5];
        tests[0] = new Test(){Name = "A"};

        var consumer = new Consumer();
        consumer.test = tests[0];

        Console.WriteLine(consumer.test.Name);   //Prints A
        tests[0] = new Test(){Name = "B"};
        Console.WriteLine(consumer.test.Name);   //Would like this to point to new object and print B
    }
}

class Test
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class Consumer
{
    public Test test {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to implement this kind of functionality directly in c#. In words, is it possible for Consumer.test to point to whatever Test instance is located in tests[0], so that when the array elements value changes, I still have access to that new value. Or, put another way, is it possible to hold a reference to a reference of an object instance? I understand that a workaround would be to just create a container class to hold a reference to a Test object and pass that around, but again, I was wondering if it was possible to do just do this directly.

Comment: I'd first ask why you want to do this? What problem are you looking to solve? There could be ways you could approach this problem, but they maybe more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: You could wrap it in another object, but really I think this is an X-Y problem.

Comment: Why can't you just call `consumer.test = tests[0];` again? That would satisfy your second comment.

Comment: For example, you could make `Consumer.test` be a `Func<Test>` instead of `Test`, but it could get pretty ugly.

Comment: The problem this solves is illustrated in the example: store a reference to an array element, so that when the array elements value changes, I still have access to that new value. The simplest way I can think of to do this would be to just create a container class, but I was just wondering if it is possible to do this directly somehow in C#.

Comment: It is not possible to do directly; you'll have to make a type that represents the indirected operation.

Comment: For variables of *unmanaged* types you can store a *pointer* to a variable, but that is extremely dangerous; you are responsible for ensuring that the variable is alive and does not move for the duration of the lifetime of the pointer.  Class types are not *unmanaged* types, so this won't work for you regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that by creating your own delegate wrapper class

```
class MyRef<T> 
{
    private Func<T> getter;

    public MyRef(Func<T> getter)
    {
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return getter(); }
    }
}
```

Modify your Consumer class to the following (Add a constructor and modify data types to utilise the delegate wrapper:

```
class Consumer
{
    public MyRef<Test> test { get; set; }

    public Consumer(MyRef<Test> t){
        test = t;   
    }
}
```

and your Consumer declaration in Main becomes

```
var consumer = new Consumer(new MyRef<Test>(() => tests[0]));
```

You will need to update your calls from Consumer to:

```
Console.WriteLine(consumer.test.Value.Name);
```

Here's a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a12Gyt)

Comment: Good answer; I note that it is a duplicate of my answer from 2010 to the same question. I'll close this question as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256048/store-a-reference-to-a-value-type/2258102#2258102

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before, but in *limited* scenarios. In most cases I've ended up refactoring to avoid the extra level of indirection because this kind of need can often be symptomatic of a poor design.

You can create a generic `Reference` class and hold a reference to that instead of the underlying object. If you do this, you will probably want to hand out an `IReference` interface to the "read-side" or consumers, and an `IChangeReference` to the "write-side" so that the contents of the reference can be manipulated.

```
public interface IReference<T>
{
    T Value { get;
}

public interface IChangeReference<T>
{
    void SetValue(T value);
}

public class Reference<T>: IReference<T>, IChangeReference<T>
{
    public Reference(T value) => Value = value;

    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(T value) => Value = value;
}

public class SomeConsumer
{
    private IReference<string> someField;
    ...
}
```